# Wrong images, regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I need a little bit of help. I got an assignment for school, I need to make a regular expressionscript which get an image (and later upload to the database, but that's not the problem). The real problem is that I get an array with all images from the page, but should be one image, which is: 
`data-src-l="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg"`
this is the code from the whole image:

```
  <li>
    <a href="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg">
      <img
       itemprop="image"
       alt="Jesus Remember Me - Taize Songs (2CD)"
       src="/WebRoot/AsaphNL/Shops/asaphnl/5422/8F43/62EE/D698/EF8E/4DEB/AED5/3B0E/80203122_xs.jpg"
       data-src-xs="/WebRoot/AsaphNL/Shops/asaphnl/5422/8F43/62EE/D698/EF8E/4DEB/AED5/3B0E/80203122_xs.jpg"
       data-src-s="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122_s.jpg"

       data-src-m="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122_m.jpg"

       data-src-l="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg"
     />
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

This is the code with PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$url = "http://www.asaphshop.nl/epages/asaphnl.sf/nl_NL/?ObjectPath=/Shops/asaphnl/Products/80203122";
$htmlcode = file_get_contents($url);
$pattern = "/<img\s[^>]*?src\s*=\s*['\"]([^'\"]*?)['\"][^>]*?>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $htmlcode, $matches);
//print_r ($matches);
$image = ($matches[0]);
$image = str_replace('src="/', 'src="http://www.asaphshop.nl/', $image);
print_r ($image);
?>
```

UPDATE: in front of the imagelink must be the link to `http://www.asaphshop.nl`, so it will look into the site for the image. not inside my localhost. If you dont understand me, you can ask ;)

Comment: So you want images one in `data-src-l` and not from `src` right?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/fG9sW8/1

Comment: use a dom parser instead of regex.

Comment: @Rikesh that's right!

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I need to do this assignment with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(<img\s[^>]*?data-src-l\s*=\s*['\"])([^'\"]*?['\"])([^>]*?>)
```

Try this.This will give the required `img`.Replace by `$1http://www.asaphshop.nl$2$3`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/29

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper2.php on line 6

Comment: Which src? There are a few src's...

Comment: yeah. it didn't work before... that's the reason i'm asking for some help

Comment: yes, I had the warning before only it was a "c" instead of an "]"...
and i saw the demo. The answer i need is that http://www.asaphshop.nl in front of the code of data-src-l. you know what i mean?

Comment: it's the site where the image comes from. if i dont paste that part in front, it will search in my localhost(and it will find nothing inside ofcourse because the images aren't there.

Comment: yes i need to put the link before the data-src-l (or "/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg")

Comment: it already stands inside the update

Comment: Finally :).................glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

> I need a little bit of help. I got an assignment for school, I need to make a regular expression script which get an image (and later upload to the database, but that's not the problem).

Tell your school that regular expressions are [**not** the best tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2016221).

Sure, there is this argument that [regular expressions are not so regular](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) and can be used for tasks such as palindrome matching. But that doesn't mean you *should* use them, since it will cause a lot of headache to you *and* other developers that might need to work with your code later.

What you should use instead is a proper HTML/XML parser.

Fortunately enough, PHP has what it needs, and it's called [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.domdocument.php). Take a look at its [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/pl/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method, for example. You could use it to retrieve images. Then you could iterate through all the attributes and parse them the way you want.

Not only it's safer since you don't have to worry about edge cases, it's also more readable.

Comment: yeah sure it is! but my school sais that's not the point, they want us to learn how it works not if it's the best way to do it.

Comment: after a few times asking my teacher told me it's ok to use DOMDocument, but i never used it, can you explain me please?

Comment: It's all in the manual...